# Where exactly is this object being stored? (Swift)

Tags: swift, function, memory, heap-memory, stack-memory

Consider the following code:

```
class Foo
{

}

func foo() -> (Void -> Foo)
{
    var foo = Foo()
    return { foo }
}

var fooGen = foo()
```

Now whenever I call `fooGen`, I get my stored `Foo` instance. But where exactly is `foo` being stored? Is it inside the stack? And if so, then what is it's lifetime?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both classes and closures are *reference types*.

```
var foo = Foo()
```

creates a `Foo` object on the heap, and stores a
(strong) reference to that object in the local stack variable `foo`.

```
return { foo }
```

creates a closure which captures `foo`, so that the closure holds
another (strong) reference to that object.
On return from the function, the local `foo` variable goes out of scope,
to that only one reference from the closure remains.

```
var fooGen = foo()
```

makes `fooGen` a reference to the returned closure (which in turn has
a reference to the `Foo` object):

```
fooGen -> closure -> Foo object
```

So the `Foo` object exists as long as the `fooGen` reference exists
(assuming that no additional strong references are created).

Demo:

```
class Foo
{
    deinit {
        println("deinit")
    }
}

func foo() -> (Void -> Foo)
{
    var foo = Foo()
    return { foo }
}

if true {
    var fooGen = foo()
    println("foo")
}

println("done")
```

Output:

```
foo
deinit
done
```

The object is destroyed when program control leaves the scope of `fooGen`.